# One DC, two subnets, two ISP connections

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, isp

I got a problem configuring my company network. The situation is difficult because there are 2 companies with two ISP connections but using the same file server. No security or administrative tool was involved until now, only two subnets and two Win workgroups were used. I would like to introduce a DC (one AD for the two companies, because they are connected in business and have the same owner) and I would like to configure the two companies to use the two different ISP services. How should I configure the network? My idea is that I will create (actually it's already done) two subnets with to default gateways and each connects to a LAN port of the DC. The problem I found that the second subnet simply can't find the DC, at least the DNS does not work. How should I configure my DNS or how should I reconfigure my whole network?
Thank you for the suggestions.

András

Answer (score 1):

I thougth you should install 2 domain controllers in each location (same domain), establish VPN connection between domain controllers and specify a routes to access form one network to other.
Configure DNS in the following way: first DNS to own subnet DNS (installed on DC or any other server in subnet), second one to remote and each ISP DNS in forwarders list.

Comment: If each site has 2 DCs, why would you put a remote DC in as your second DNS server? Use the second local DC.